# android sampling profiler

Tags: android, profiler

Could somebody point me out for a sampling profiler for android apps?
Searched "entire" web, nothing found.
Any links are highly appreciated. May be some ideas on how to make it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's dalvik.system.profiler.SamplingProfiler in newer releases (>= Honeycomb, iirc). It's not public, though, so for now you'd have to use reflection to get at it. We should do something about that in a future release...